# Spring HTTPSession on REDIS is slow

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, redis

I have implemented Spring HTTPSession on REDIS. But however, I find the performance low as compared to spring internal (in memory) HTTP session generation and management. Web server used is TOMCAT 8, JVM is Hotspot and Java version 8.

The implementation is as mention in the following link

https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#httpsession-redis

Following is the output of the Jmeter run kept on the same machine in both the cases:

1. With Redis : ~2800 rps (request per second)
2. Without Redis (Spring Session) : ~7000 rps
3. CPU utilization : 70% - 80%

Here is my Jmeter Run Configuration:

1. POST URL
2. Jmeter Threads - 1000
3. Rampup 5
4. Continuous Loopback
5. Run time: 5 minutes

Hardware configuration:

1. Core i5
2. 8 GB ram
3. 4 cores

OS:
Linux Debian OS

What can be possible reasons for this. Are there any alternate configurations or  implementations to achieve the said performance.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Redis sessions will be accessed over network so because of this it might be slow. Is the redis on same server as tomcat?

Comment: Even if it's on the same server, it still has more to do than access memory, so I don't see what's so surprising about this.

Comment: yes the round trip always costs. It's all about the network latency. You can use pipeline commands to reduce them. But you can't achieve what your spring session can give.

Comment: @AmitSadafule I have tried both, same as well as different machine. The current config is of the same Machine. On different Machine 3 in total for (Tomcat , Redis and Jmeter) with same config and 100mbps network link, the performance degrades further to 2000 and 6400 respectively.

Comment: @KarthikeyanGopall If that is the case, I find many blogs and Articles claiming Redis Session is far better then Spring Session. That would be what terms then? And What should be preferred ?

Comment: @Kayaman Is there any Performance Bench Mark between the both? Like which is more preferred?

Comment: @Krishnaveer When you use spring's internal inmemory you are bound inside your JVM there is no need for an external call, round trip, network latency. When you use redis you have to give an external call. You can never ever achieve the speed of retrieving JVM's in memory values in any other external in memory stores. Keeping too much of memory inside your JVM is not advisable as it would affect the user threads and cause GCs. In order to avoid that you can have redis as a storage for those data. Also you can store more data in redis than in your JVM.

Comment: @Krishnaveer could you provide a reference to articles claiming Redis Session being better than Spring Session?

Comment: @Krishnaveer: As per me, redis http session should be slower than than JVM memory accesses. But to improve performance you could check threadpool setting given to redis connections while initialisation. What is your threadpool value? Try increasing/modifying that.

Comment: We are seeing serious performance degradation to the point of failure when Spring Redis is enabled. I don't have any numbers, but after many seemingly random Selenium test failures, the best explanation is that this is slowing down our webapp performance under tomcat to the point of failure under heavy load testing.

One problem we were able to confirm is that static files (ie jquery.js) were being returned with the wrong mimetype (text/html) and were getting truncated. This caused all kinds of havoc that was terribly hard to track down. Bypassing tomcat for static files fixed it partially.